# Declarative creation dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect and attribute "title" (Dojo 1.4)

Tags: javascript, html, dojo

I use Dojo 1.4 and try to create `dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect`

```
<select id="sel1" class="soria" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" multiple="true"
size="23" style="width:267px; height:260px;">
<option value="1" title="1">1</option>
<option value="2" title="2">2</option>
<option value="3" title="3">3</option>
</select>
```

but I do not see `title` attribute in generated checkboxes. What I do wrong?

**UPD.**  Any way to get all html attributes which was defined in object(CheckedMultiSelect)?

Comment: Why ask two identical questions? Go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11502836/dojo-set-attribute-from-json-as-html-attribute/11503138#11503138 and edit your question instead

Comment: That creation of CheckedMultiSelect from store. But this is declarative from HTML element

Comment: its still same topic.. but you havent gone there and read what was stated in the answer (was updated nearly a day ago).. It is _not possible to do via normal 'channels', declarative as well as programmatic. The widget is and old story and not the top dawg under dojox widgets.. You can extend the module yourself - or use one of the methods ive given in the above linked answer.

Comment: @ 'Any way to get all html attributes which was defined in object(CheckedMultiSelect)?' No, it only tracks *option* and *value*. When you do new CheckedMultiSelect({}, 'sel1'); (or parse it), the old DOM is pouf Gone! Read 11502836..